# AutoFixture and dynamic fixture type Injections

Tags: c#, autofixture

I am very new to AutoFixture and am having some issues trying to dynamically Freeze and Inject types.  Here is an example of the code I had that I was repeating all over the place to get fake repositories injected into my fixture:

```
FakeRepository<Application> applicationRepository = fixture.Freeze<FakeRepository<Application>>();
fixture.Inject<IReadRepository<Application>>(applicationRepository);
fixture.Inject<IWriteRepository<Application>>(applicationRepository);
```

After getting all of the types in the entity assembly dynamically using reflection, I would like to do something like this:

```
Type repositoryReadInterfaceType = typeof(IReadRepository<>).MakeGenericType(entityType);
Type repositoryWriteInterfaceType = typeof(IWriteRepository<>).MakeGenericType(entityType);
Type repositoryType = typeof(FakeRepository<>).MakeGenericType(entityType);

var repositoryObject = fixture.Freeze(repositoryType);
fixture.Inject(repositoryReadInterfaceType, repositoryObject);
fixture.Inject(repositoryWriteInterfaceType, repositoryObject);
```

However, there are no overloads which support the desired injections I would like.  Is there any other way of going about this that I'm missing?  Or, perhaps, is this just not possible?

**Edit for what I have tried:**

**Attempt 1 using TypeRelay:**

```
var repositoryObject = fixture.Freeze(repositoryType);

fixture.Customizations.Add(new TypeRelay(repositoryReadInterfaceType, repositoryType));
fixture.Customizations.Add(new TypeRelay(repositoryWriteInterfaceType, repositoryType));
```

**Attempt 2 using SpecimenBuilderNodeFactory:**

```
var repositoryObject = fixture.Freeze(repositoryType);

fixture.Customizations.Insert(
    0,
    SpecimenBuilderNodeFactory.CreateTypedNode(
        repositoryReadInterfaceType,
        new FixedBuilder(repositoryObject)
    )
);
fixture.Customizations.Insert(
    0,
    SpecimenBuilderNodeFactory.CreateTypedNode(
        repositoryWriteInterfaceType,
        new FixedBuilder(repositoryObject)
    )
);
```

**Attempt 3 of just using dynamic Freezing:**

In a separate method using Reflection, I am freezing all of the fake repositories like so:

```
var repositoryObject = fixture.Freeze(repositoryType);
```

Then in my main method I am injecting the read and write repository types manually:

```
fixture.Inject<IReadRepository<Application>>(fixture.Create<FakeRepository<Application>>());
fixture.Inject<IWriteRepository<Application>>(fixture.Create<FakeRepository<Application>>());
```

**All of the above attempts result in the Read and Write types seeming to not point at the same FakeRepository.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated answer, original further down**

This repro works (the tests passes):

```
public interface IFoo
{
    string FooIt();
}

public interface IBar
{
    string BarIt();
}

public class FooBar : IFoo, IBar
{
    public FooBar(Guid id)
    {
        this.Id = id;
    }

    public Guid Id { get; private set; }

    public string BarIt()
    {
        return this.Id.ToString();
    }

    public string FooIt()
    {
        return this.Id.ToString();
    }
}

public class Tests
{
    [Fact]
    public void AllIsFrozen()
    {
        var fixture = new Fixture();
        fixture.Customize(new FreezingCustomization(typeof(FooBar)));
        fixture.Customizations.Add(new TypeRelay(typeof(IFoo), typeof(FooBar)));
        fixture.Customizations.Add(new TypeRelay(typeof(IBar), typeof(FooBar)));

        var foo = fixture.Create<IFoo>();
        var bar = fixture.Create<IBar>();
        var foobar = fixture.Create<FooBar>();

        Assert.Equal(foobar.Id.ToString(), foo.FooIt());
        Assert.Equal(foobar.Id.ToString(), bar.BarIt());
    }
}
```

---

**Original answer**

I haven't tried this, so it may neither compile, nor work...

Everything you inject is eventually packaged into an `ISpecimenBuilder` and placed in `Fixture.Customizations`. You could try to use a `FixedBuilder` and package that into a typed node.

Something like this could work:

```
fixture.Customizations.Insert(
    0,
    SpecimenBuilderNodeFactory.CreateTypedNode(
        myType,
        new FixedBuilder(myObject)));
```

You could also use `Customizations.Add`, but note that the order in that collection matters (the first match wins).

Comment: Thank you for the reply!  I gave it a shot and it didn't seem to work.  For some reason the Write and Read repositories don't seem to be pointing to the same FakeRepository.  I gave the TypeRelay a shot as well, but that gave me the same results.

Comment: @AnonAll112 Oh, yeah, I'd forgotten about `TypeRelay`s. Those ought to work. Can you share what you tried?

Comment: I have updated my original post with the 2 blocks of code I have tried.

Comment: I get the feeling it may have to do with the Freeze.  From my first example of the repetitive way I am doing the injections, I tried to only do the Freezing dynamically using Reflection and then have the fixture create the FakeRepository object to inject the IReadRepository and IWriteRepository manually, which ended in the same result.  I will create an Attempt 3 to show this scenario.

Comment: I tried exactly what you have and I figured out the line that is my problem. You have: fixture.Freeze<FooBar>(); whereas I have: fixture.Freeze(typeof(FooBar));. Is there a way to get the Freeze to behave the same way as your example without explicitly defining the type?

Comment: @AnonAll112 Updated